# ROS_INFO can't print a ROS message?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just spent around almost 2 hrs trying to fix a problem, that didn't even exist in the first place. All because ROS_INFO was printing the wrong thing (essentially printing garbage) when I tried to do something like

```
std::string s = "..."
ROS_INFO("result: %s", s)
```

I had to print an **std::string** because I was trying to print a ROS message, **which I had to parse myself**, because I couldn't JUST PRINT THE MESSAGE:

```
void soemclass::jointPositionsCallback(const some_msgs::JointsPositions::ConstPtr& msg){
    ROS_INFO(msg); // <- COMPILE ERROR
}
```

Is there really no way to **JUST PRINT THE MESSAGE**? Why can't I just print the `std::string` as well?

I feel this should be so much easier.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359553/ros_info-can%27t-print-a-ros-message?/) by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2020-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The non-stream versions take C-style strings (a null terminated character array), so they work with something like this:

```
ROS_INFO("a c-style string");
```

If you want to print a std::string you can do it one of two ways:

```
ROS_INFO(s.c_str());  // this prints a C-style string
ROS_INFO_STREAM(s);
```

For your message, this should work:

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-14**:
Obligatory link to the wiki page: [roscpp/Overview/Logging](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging).

**Comment by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on 2020-08-16**:
Ok, I didn't know about the ROS_INFO_STREAM, thank you. Do you know if the ROS message objects have a built-in "to_string()" method?

**Comment by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on 2020-08-16**:
@gvdroorn I saw this documentation. But, as you can see, I just wanted to make a simple logging of an std::string and a ros message. This is a very complicated documentation for such a basic function, and the documentation doesn't even mention the supposedly correct method to do this, which is `ROS_INFO_STREAM()`. The purpose of this question is also to bring awareness to this issue, these little things make ROS unnecessarily hard to use.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2020-08-17**:
Yes, the ROS messages have a "<<" operator, which is how streams work.